# Android NDK failed with libutils.so: undefined reference to `__pthread_gettid'

Tags: android-ndk

I try to make my android application with a native shared library but I get below error:

```
Debug//local/arm64-v8a/libutils.so: undefined reference to `__pthread_gettid' clang++: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I'm using Android NDK r13b. In my makefile have:

Application.mk

```
.....
APP_PLATFORM := android-19
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
.....
```

Android.mk

```
.....
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libutils
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(APP_ABI)/libutils.so <= already 64bit lib
include $(PREBUILT_SHARED_LIBRARY)
.....
```

Answer (score 0):

`__pthread_gettid` is not an NDK API. It's in the `LIBC_PRIVATE` version section: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/bionic/+/master/libc/libc.map.txt#1481